# Positive definiteness of Dirac hamiltonian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, grassmann-numbers

In David Tong's notes, he says that the Hamiltonian (4.92) is positive definite ( see page 112 of chapter [five](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/five.pdf) ). Here is equation (4.92) from chapter [four](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/four.pdf).
$$ E = \int d^3 x \ T^{00} = \int d^3 x \ \bar{\psi} \gamma^0 \partial_t{\psi} = \int d^3 x \ {\psi}^\dagger \gamma^0 ( -i \gamma^i \partial_i +m ) \psi \tag{4.92}$$

Can someone help me in seeing why this is positive definite?

I tried to write the operator $\gamma^0 ( -i \gamma^i \partial_i)$ as a matrix in Fourier space. But it seems like it will be a matrix with zero trace and negative determinant. This means that some of the eigenvalues will be positive and some negative. So it can't be positive-definite (or negative-definite) matrix.

Comment: Maybe one can transform the volume integral of the term with gradient using the Gauss theorem into a surface integral over boundary of the region, which then for some nice enough $\psi$ vanishes as the boundary expands to infinity, and the remaining term looks like it could be positive definite. But I did not really check this, it needs careful analysis.

Comment: Indeed, the first quantisation Hamiltonian is not positive definite, the normally ordered second quantisation one is positive defined. The converse result holds for the electric charge.

Answer (score 1):

The Hamtiltonian is defined as the normal ordered operator

$$H=:\int d^{3}x\psi^{\dagger}(x)i\partial_{0}\psi(x):\,\,,$$

where $\psi(x)$ can be expanded using creation and annihilation operators as follows

$$\psi(x)=\int\frac{d^{3}k}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{m}{k_{0}}\sum_{\alpha}\left[b_{\alpha}(k)u^{\alpha}(k)e^{-ikx}+d_{\alpha}^{\dagger}(k)v^{\alpha}(k)e^{ikx}\right].$$

Plugging in the above expression, one finds

\begin{align}
&\int d^{3}x\psi^{\dagger}(x)i\partial_{0}\psi(x) \\
&=\int\frac{d^{3}k}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{m}{k_{0}}k_{0}\sum_{\alpha}\left[b_{\alpha}^{\dagger}(k)b_{\alpha}(k)-d_{\alpha}(k)d_{\alpha}^{\dagger}(k)\right],
\end{align}

where spinor normalization conditions

\begin{align}
\bar{u}^{\alpha}(k)u^{\beta}(k)&=\delta^{\alpha\beta} \\
\bar{v}^{\alpha}(k)v^{\beta}(k)&=-\delta^{\alpha\beta} \\
\bar{u}^{\alpha}(k)v^{\beta}(k)&=0 \\
(u^{\alpha})^{\dagger}(k)u^{\beta}(k)&=(v^{\alpha})^{\dagger}(k)v^{\beta}(k)=\frac{k_{0}}{m}\delta^{\alpha\beta}
\end{align}

have been used.

For spinor fields, odd operators $b_{\alpha}$ and $d_{\alpha}$ satisfy anti-commuting relations. Therefore, under the normal ordering operation, one has an extra minus sign for the second term:

$$:d_{\alpha}(k)d_{\alpha}^{\dagger}(k):=-d_{\alpha}^{\dagger}(k)d_{\alpha}(k).$$

Thus, the integrand of $H$ is positive definite, and so is $H$.